# What is the accepted convention for when to use an object containing objects vs an array of objects in JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am currently in the process of writing a GUI which fundamentally allows users to edit/populate/delete a number of settings files, where the settings are stored in JSON, using AJAX.

I have limited experience with JavaScript (I have little experience with anything beyond MATLAB to be frank), however I find myself restructuring my settings structure because of the semantics of working with an object containing more objects, rather than an array of objects. In C# I would do this using a KeyValuePair, however the JSON structure prevents me from doing what I'd really like to do here, and I was wondering whether there was an accepted convention for do this in JavaScript which I should adopt now, rather than making these changes and finding that I cause more issues than I solve.

The sample data structure, which has similar requirements to many of my structures, accepts any number of years, and within these any number of events, and within these a set number of values.

Here is the previous structure:

```
{"2013":
    {
    "someEventName":
        {
        "data1":"foo",
        "data2":"bar",
        ...},
    ...},
...}
```

Here is my ideal structure, where the year/event name operates as a key of type string for a value of type Array:

```
["2013":
    [
    "someEventName":
        {
        "data1":"foo",
        "data2":"bar",
        ...},
    ...],
...]
```

As far as I am aware, this would be invalid JSON notation, so here is my proposed structure:

```
[{"Key":"2013",
  "Value":
      [{"Key":"someEventName",
        "Value":
            {
            "data1":"foo",
            "data2":"bar",
            ...}
      },
      ...]
},
...]
```

My proposed "test" for whether something should be an object containing objects or an array of objects is "does my sub-structure take a fixed, known number of objects?" If yes, design as object containing objects; if no, design as array of objects.

I am required to filter through this structure frequently to find data/values, and I don't envisage ever exploiting the index functionality that using an array brings, however pushing and removing data from an array is much more flexible than to an object and it feels like using an object containing objects deviates from the class model of OOP; on the other hand, the methods for finding my data by "Key" all seem simpler if it is an object containing objects, and I don't envisage myself using Prototype methods on these objects anyway so who cares about breaking OOP.

**Response 1**
In the previous structure to add a year, for example, the code would be `OBJ["2014"]={}`; in the new structure it would be `OBJ.push({"Key":"2014", "Value":{}})`; both of these solutions are similarly lacking in their complexity.

Deleting is similarly trivial in both cases.

However, if I want to manipulate the value of an event, say, using a function, if I pass a pointer to that object to the function and try to superceed the whole object in the reference, it won't work: I am forced to copy the original event (using jQuery or worse) and reinsert it at the parent level. With a "Value" attribute, I can overwrite the whole value element however I like, provided I pass the entire `{"Key":"", "Value":""}` object to the function. It's an awful lot cleaner in this situation for me to use the array of objects method.

I am also basing this change to arrays on the wealth of other responses on stack**overflow** which encourage the use of them instead of objects.

Comment: Could you detail what you mean by "pushing and removing data from an array is much more flexible than to an object"? Keep in mind that in JavaScript/JSON, the Object type generally serves double-duty as both its formally-structured OOP "Objects", and its Map/Dictionary-esque key-mappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're going to do is iterate over your objects, then an array of objects makes more sense. If these are settings and people are going to need to look up a specific one then the original object notation is better. the original allows people write code like

```
var foo = settings['2013'][someEventName].data1
```

whereas getting that data out of the array of objects would requires iterating through them to find the one with the key: 2013 which depending on the length of the list will cause performance issues.

Pushing new data to the object is as simple as

```
settings['2014'] = {...}
```

and deleting data from an object is also simple

```
delete settings['2014']
```